# Sharing i18n instance Translations not working in my npm package & also in my second app

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js, react-i18next

I've created a package using react, next, typescript, tailwind & bundled using webpack, and added translation with i18next and react-i18next. What i want to achieve is sharing translation along with the components/pages in the package
I've already managed to share components & pages but it's just their translations don't work in 2nd app so i decided to create an i18n instance and share that.
here are my config files in app1 ie. package app -

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import enTranslation from './public/locales/en.json'
import jaTranslation from './public/locales/ja.json';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'ja'],
    backend: {
      loadPath: `/locales/{{lng}}.json`,
    },
    resources: {
      en: { translation: enTranslation },
      ja: { translation: jaTranslation },
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

src/index.ts Here i share all things i want to export from the package -

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
export { default as i18n } from '../i18n';
export { default as ReportPage } from '../pages/reports/index';
```

webpack.config.js -

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      assert: require.resolve('assert'),
      buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
      util: require.resolve('util'),
      fs: false,
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
      zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
    },
    // existing resolve properties
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    next: 'next',
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: 'static', // Generates a static report file
      openAnalyzer: false, // Will not open the report in a new window
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: 'public', to: 'public' } // copies all files from public to dist/public
      ],
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
};
```

and my en.json and ja.json are in root dir - public/locales/en.json like so

the problem is when i import it in my app2 (Next js app / electron)
_app.tsx -

```
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
// import Layout from '../components/layouts/layout';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { i18n } from '@test/report-module-v2';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import '../styles/globals.css';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('language')) {
      router.push(router.route, router.asPath, {
        locale: localStorage.getItem('language'),
      });
    } else {
      router.push(router.route, router.asPath, {
        locale: 'en',
      });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(i18n, 'i18n');
    
    i18n.changeLanguage(router.locale);
  }, [router.locale]);
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);
  return getLayout(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </I18nextProvider>,
  );
}
export default App;
```

and the component I'm importing a ReportPage Components from package but it doesn't seem to work -

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ReportPage } from '@test/report-module-v2';
import UserLayout from '../../components/layouts/user-layout';
import PageContainer from '../../components/users/page-container';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { i18n } from '@test/report-module-v2';
const Test = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(router.locale);
    
  }, [])
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  console.log(i18n, 'i18n');

  
  
    return (
    <div>

      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}> 
        <ReportPage />
      </I18nextProvider>
    </div>)
}
Test.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
    return (
      <UserLayout>
        <PageContainer>{page}</PageContainer>
      </UserLayout>
    );
  };
export default Test;
```

Suppose i locally create an i18n.js file in app2 and put the JSON files manually in public/locales and import a this i18n instance from the i18n.js file in my _app.tsx. In that case, my change language functionality button works for all translations except for the ReportPage from the package. any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any guidance/resources would be highly appreciated. Both my apps are built with Next js. Only 2nd app uses Next js with Electron
If I just import i18n from their respective files both app translation work. But I'm creating a module and want to share the translations too :3 Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks. You can check the app1 code here if you want to see the whole code of report page. It's just a dumb component that fetches public API and renders it in a tanstack table - https://github.com/akiijadhav/report-module-v2.git

Comment: Is there any update on the above issue ?